# Is it possible to have a js.erb partial in rails 3.0?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

If it is possible, how can I run it from another js.erb-file?

Trying to keep things DRY!

EDIT: 
Explanation: I have a js.erb routine in search/index.js.erb. I want to use the same routine in location/index.js.erb. Therefore I wondered if I could make a partial containg js.erb code, so that I don't have to copy the routine from the first index.js.erb file to the other one.

Comment: can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Added explanation to the original post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YES. you can have a common partial (say in a folder: app/views/partials) and use that partial's path inside your `*.js.erb` file like this `<%= render :partial => path_to_partial, :locals => { ....} %>`

If you want to extract the html string out of a partial you can also use

```
render_to_string :partial => path_to_partial
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your rendered file begins with an underscore (i.e.:

if you intend to

```
<%= render :partial => 'myroutine.js.erb', :locals => { ....} %>
```

the file should be named _myroutine.js.erb)