# Best way to include javascript in Rails via content_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I have some pages in my Rails application that need one off bits of javascript to be included, ideally just before the `</body>` tag. There is no real need to have this javascript included on EVERY page since most don't use it. I've found a way to make this work, but I think the code is terrible.

How would you do the same thing or how would you refactor the existing code?

View simplified, sample code on gist.github.com:
https://gist.github.com/scottswezey/ffc7bf52041b976b710a

(Or see the same code below:)

**application.html.erb (Layout):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  ...
  </head>

  <body>
    ...
    <script>
    $(function() {
      <%= yield(:js) %>
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**some_view_file.html.erb (View):**

```
<%
str = <<END_OF_STRING
$('.modal').modal()
END_OF_STRING

content_for :js do
  str.html_safe
end
%>
```

Comment: Don't know if I understand your question, but you can set a variable (e.g. `@js_code`) in the action in the controller, and use `<% if @js_code %> <script> ...` in application.html.erb?

Comment: I'm not trying to selectively display the js code, I'm trying to put snippets of code into view files and have them included in the layout with content_for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever do it this way: JavaScript doesn't belong in HTML. Just put an appropriate `<script>` tag in the page, referring to an external JS file, something like this:

application.html.haml

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    = yield :javascript
  %body
    = yield
```

view file

```
- content_for :javascript do
  = javascript_include_tag 'modal'
```

app/assets/modal.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').modal();
}
```

This keeps everything nicely separated.

Comment: You say it doesn't belong in "HTML", I guess you mean `body`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup for dissenting opinions where to put javascript tags.

Comment: @Christopher I meant that JS code doesn’t belong *anywhere* in an HTML document. It should be included from an external JS file with `<script src='modal.js'>`, as I did here.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to add a .js.erb partial with your JS and render it under the body?

edit: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10113547/1283742

Comment: My initial intent had been to keep this helper code next to the view code (HTML) that it was powering. I'm not sure a separate partial is the best solution, but it did get me thinking that I should look into the asset pipeline for this. Still not my ideal, but maybe "better."

Comment: Downvoting: there's no reason to use JS partials when you can just have a `<script src='something.js'>` tag, and no reason to use .js.erb when you can manipulate the DOM instead.

Comment: @ScottS. No HTML document should contain JavaScript, so keeping it adjacent to the HTML isn't a good idea. Rather, keep the *reference to the external JS file* near the HTML if you want to.